# Laravel - Criando select com com Form::select + Model::lists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando criar um select com o seguinte código:

Meu controller está assim:

```
public function create(){
    $marcas = Marca::lists('descricao', 'id')->toArray();
    return view('sistema.modelos.create', ['marcas'=>$marcas]);
}
```

Minha view está assim:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'sistema.modelos.store']) !!}
{!! Form::select('marca_id', $marcas ) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Trying to get property of non-objec
```

Alguém já passou por isso? Sabe como fazer isso?

editando---

Já fiz isso:

```
$marcas = Marca::all(['id', 'descricao']);
return view('sistema.modelos.create', compact('marcas',$marcas));
```

conforme o link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508297/laravel-5-how-to-populate-select-box-from-database-with-id-value-and-name-value

Nesse caso o select até é renderizado, mas fica assim:

```
<select name="marca_id"><option value="0">{id : 1 , descricao : NOME}</option></select>
```

Comment: Esse compact não tem nada a ver. Não precisa passar a variável nele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve inicializar o select com uma array e não uma collection, tente alterar de

```
$marcas = Marca::lists('descricao', 'id');
```

para

```
$marcas = Marca::lists('descricao', 'id')->toArray();
```

ou no Laravel 5.2

```
$marcas = Marca::pluck('descricao', 'id');
```

Se você quiser um valor neutro para o select, tente utilizar o atributo `placeholder` ou dar um `append` antes de transformar a collection em uma array.

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tente alterar de ->all(); para ->toArray();.

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Assim:

$marcas = Marca::all(['id', 'descricao']);
return view('sistema.modelos.create', compact('marcas',$marcas));

até monta o select mas desenha o objeto inteiro

Comment: Na verdade com a resposta que eu te passei é para funcionar com 100% de certeza, podemos investigar as outras partes do seu código?

Comment: coloquei mais informações... veja faz favor

Comment: Mesmo com o Marca::pluck('descricao', 'id') não funcionou, segue dando o mesmo erro:

Comment: Consegue de alguma forma me mostrar o log completo do erro?

Comment: Está certo o modo que estou passando a variável '$marcas' para a view?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42736/discussion-between-rafael-berro-and-andersonsouza).

Comment: O erro estava no meu próprio código em outra parte. A solução do Rafael Berro funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Qual a melhor forma para criar option vazio ?

Comment: Pode dar um append na collection, antes de usar o toArray(), ou pode colocar o atributo placeholder no html do campo.